# vb.net datagrid header using th tag

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

is it possible to use  tag when bind datagrid in vb.net ?

current result is :

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Header</td>
</tr>
</thead>
```

What I want is :

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Header</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I think you can with the listview not the datagrid

Comment: I cannot change to listview cause all the grid has used asp:datagrid, I thing it will take more time to change all the page.

Answer (score 0):

The data grid tag needs the property "UseAccessibleHeader" and a value of True.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="BigDataGrid" UseAccessibleHeader="True" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    ...
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```